# BottomTabNavigator coming on top instead of bottom in React Native expo mobile app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am developing a mobile react native expo app. I am using BottomTabNavigator (NavigationContainer). As the name suggests it should appear at the bottom but it is incorrectly appearing on top.

I already have another image (logo.png) on the top of the screen and the navigationbar  (or NavigationContainer) is also coming on top and overlapping above the image. Please help me resolve this issue. See my code below:

In the below code `MyTabs` is the Navigator created from `createBottomTabNavigator()`. This is incorrectly appearing on top of the screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image,  StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MyTabs from './navigator/AppNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight: 0 }} >
        <View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image source={logo} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />

                <Text style={{color: '#888', fontSize: 18, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                To share a photo from your phone with a friend or anyone, just press the button below!
                </Text>
            </View>

            <View >
                <NavigationContainer >
                        <MyTabs />        // This is incorrectly coming on top of screen.
                </NavigationContainer>
            </View>

        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
     alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NavigationContainer` should be the outermost component in `App`. This then wraps the `Tab.Navigator` component (in your case `MyTabs`), where you create tabs linked to each of your components. Inside your components, you are able to utilize `SafeAreaView` to then display the image at the top of the screen. Any type of Navigation scheme has to be made the top most component in the hierarchy in react native, wrapping the rest of your components. I've altered your code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image,  StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

export default function App() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

  return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      <Tab.Navigator>  
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={myComponent} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const myComponent = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight: 0 }} >
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          <Text style={{color: '#888', fontSize: 18, alignItems: 'center'}}>To share a photo from your phone with a friend or anyone, just press the button below!</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
     alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: `BottomNavigator` is linked to the `SafeAreaView` component, so both the image and the tab selector are rendering. Like I said, `NavigationContainer` is supposed to be the top-most component in the React DOM hierarchy, wrapping the rest of the components. You link each of the screens in the Tab Navigator in order to get your components to display. Nothing is meant to be rendered **alongside** the navigator, as you originally posted. However, if you insist, you can try using CSS selectors to get the navigator to anchor to the bottom.

Comment: I'm pretty limited in how much I can help you based on the above code sample, especially since having a `Tab.Navigator` in a separate component did not work for me like it did for you with the `myTabs` component. Try linking a snack of your work and maybe I'll be able to better help you. This is a snack of my code above: https://snack.expo.io/@kaushalp/thoughtful-soda.

Comment: Great! If this post helped, please upvote and mark as the answer :)